# Instagram Basic API - Authorization issue

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I'm trying to utizlie Insatgram Basic Display API to get some information about particular Instagram post. I'm going through Facebook API documentation, but there are some inconsistencies I can't seem to find solution to. My goal is to create a private app I can use on my website, that would display some information about any given Instagram post (not only from my account).

I have created FB app already and used the following url to authorize it on Instagram:

```
https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URL&scope=user_profile,user_media&response_type=code
```

This redirects me to the usual Instagram permission window, which I accept and am being redirected back to this url:

```
https://REDIRECT_URL?opauth=CODE#_
```

There are two problems from now on:
1. Facebook docs state that url parameter in return should be `code`, not `opauth`:

```
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/guides/getting-access-tokens-and-permissions
```

2. When I use value of `opauth` in the following CURL request, I get the `Invalid Authorization Code` error in return:

```
curl -X POST https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token -F "client_id=CLIENT_ID" -F "client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET" -F "grant_type=authorization_code" -F "redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URL" -F "code=OPAUTH_VALUE"
```

I have double checked every value in request and they seem to be correct. I went through authorization process several times just to be sure, but can't obtain access token no matter what.

Answer (score 0):

Found it. The `opauth` parameter was somehow a result of WordPress theme using Opauth framework. Redirected url from Instagram had value of `code` parameter replaced with new `opauth` param with it's own value.

Using different theme allowed me to get correct `code` parameter from redirect url and get access token.